# why fgetc() doesn't work well in my program (c language)?

Tags: c

```
1, 2, 3   // a.txt
```

This program is for opening the file, counting the numbers and reading the first letter of txt file.
When I tried debugging, `digit_char = fgetc(fp);` doesn't worked properly. `digit_char` was empty. I used dynamic allocation to save the numbers in the array. There was no warning but the answer was not what I wanted. (`digit_char`=`1`)
[image]

```
    FILE* fp;
    char digit_char;
    int NUM=1;
    fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    char ch;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == ',')
        {
            NUM++;
        }
    } while (ch != EOF);


    int* arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * NUM);

    digit_char = fgetc(fp);     // error...?
    
    free(arr);
    fclose(fp);
```

======

The following code `fgetc()` works very well. `1`is saved in `digit_char`

```
FILE* fp;
    char digit_char;
    int NUM=3;
    fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");


    int arr[3];

    digit_char = fgetc(fp);
    
    //free(arr);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

I don't know why the first program doesn't work well..

Comment: `char char;`? That should not even build. Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Also note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an **`int`**, which is rather important when comparing the returned value with the `int` constant `EOF`.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake I edited again

Comment: aha I just got it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have reached `EOF`, you're really at the end of the file. There's nothing more to read.

You need to [*`rewind`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind) to the beginning of the file before attempting to read again.

Or at least [*seek*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) to an earlier position.

---

Note that it's not possible to rewind or seek in the standard input stream `stdin`. To continue reading from `stdin` even after the user pressed the "end-of-file" button sequence, you need to [clear the "error"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/clearerr).

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully agree with this sentence: `"Note that it's not possible to rewind or seek in the standard input stream stdin"` -- I agree that a platform is not required to support seeking or rewinding on the standard input stream. However, the Microsoft Windows platform does define the behavior of calling `rewind` on the standard input stream (although it does not rewind the input buffer to the state it had at the start of the program, but rather clears the keyboard buffer).